# Can I create admin for each groups in django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

Let's say I have two groups named Group1 and Group2 having specific access to models. And I want to create an admin for each group so that, admin can do all CRUD done by the user of that group. Group1 admin should handle Group1 users activities and Group2 admin handle Group2 user activities. And also the user in each group can update, delete and view of its own. I want in Django admin. How can I do that?